# Switch negative pulse

Tags: switching

The following image shows a switch that, when activated, feeds a load with -10 volts. I have a microcontroller and I need to switch this, what can I use instead of the key? Npn transistor already tried but I couldn't, how to do it?!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3dTK.png)

Comment: Crop the photo, man. Crop the photo!

Comment: Search the interwebs for "high side switch".

Comment: Based on very little information, there are two basic approaches.  1.  Connect one side of the load to GND, and switch the other side of the load to the -10 V supply.  2.  Connect one side of the load to the -10 V supply, and switch the other side of the load to GND.  Which way do you want to go?  **What is the load current?**  What is the microcontroller power supply voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on very little information, here is something I did 5 years ago on another forum.  There is another way to do that that uses only one NPN transistor and a zener diode.

[image]

Comment: And you can do exactly the same thing with FETs, if that’s your bag.

Answer (score 0):

> The following image shows a switch that, when activated, feeds a load with -10 volts.

No, the power supply negative is connected to ground so that's the 0 V reference from which all other measurements are taken. That means that the switch is switching the positive and supplying +10 V to the load resistor.

> I have a microcontroller and I need to switch this, what can I use instead of the key? NPN transistor already tried but I couldn't, how to do it?

This is much simpler with an NPN transistor in the negative side of your load resistor. See [Electronics-Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4.html) for sample circuits and explanation. There's no need to write it out here again.

Answer (score 0):

To define the question better you need to have acceptance criteria or “specs” with tolerances

- V=10V +/- x%.
- PW50= pulse width at 50, max. For a switched load
- is it steady state?
- rise time= ?
- Load impedance = ? Or peak current
  or type of load with values.
- Charge Pump IC’s are used for +/-V for low current with eCaps.
- Cuk inverters maybe used for greater power.
- Single supply designs are often better.

Comment: Tony, this is as much use to the OP as a bicycle is to a fish. OP thinks that -10 V is being switched onto the load when it's a simple battery, switch in the positive and load connected to GND. We're a long from writing a specification here.

Comment: TY @Transistor that is about as helpful as a battery in backwards to a question about “a negative pulse” with 2020 hindsight ;) to a baker with advice about flour

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated version that uses only one transistor plus a zener diode.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the OP's schematic (now converted to a link for some reason). The supply negative is ground. OP is switching positive rail.

Comment: He wrote "-10V" next to the voltage symbol, which is consistent with his description,  I don't think his inexperience with a schematic editor overrides his text, which is pretty clear for an obvious noob.

Comment: You're correct. I missed that. Thanks.